# Does a rogue get precision damage during an attack of opportunity if flanking?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, rogue, opportunity-attack, sneak-attack

In the Pathfinder rules here's what it says:

> If a rogue can catch an opponent when he is unable to defend himself
>   effectively from her attack, she can strike a vital spot for extra
>   damage.
>
> The rogue's attack deals extra damage anytime her target would be
>   denied a Dexterity bonus to AC (whether the target actually has a
>   Dexterity bonus or not), or when the rogue flanks her target. This
>   extra damage is 1d6 at 1st level, and increases by 1d6 every two rogue
>   levels thereafter. Should the rogue score a critical hit with a sneak
>   attack, this extra damage is not multiplied. Ranged attacks can count
>   as sneak attacks only if the target is within 30 feet.

I just wanted to confirm, it seems as though a rogue who gets an Attack of Opportunity while flanking would get his sneak attack damage.

Am I mistaken?

Comment: Can you share what makes you think you might be mistaken?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**

An AoO while flanking is an attack while flanking, so it meets the condition and does get the bonus damage. In this context, it being an AoO doesn't change anything.